# Android Statusbar notifcation - want to run a single line of code on selecting it

Tags: android, notifications

I've been searching for this for a while and keep coming up short. However I have setup notifications before where selecting it launches an activity, now I'm trying to mod that code.

This time I'm looking for a solution to run just a single line of code when the notification is selected.  I want it to set a button from invisible to visible.  So when my notification is cleared I want the code below to take place, not launch an activity or intent:

```
    butNX.setVisibility(0);
```

Any input on the matter? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't try this, but i think it will resolve your problem.
1. Set up a Receiver where you need it.
2. Create an Intent and add the extras to it something like this: 
 `intent.putExtra("MODE","VIS");`.
3. Craete a PendingIntent which will broadcast your intent to your receiver.
   `PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(yourContext,yourReqCode,
                                                     yourIntent,yourFlags);`
4.Set notification

So while receiver will receive your broadcast it should to check what to do with this intent by data which you send...